# Export files to custom directory parallel to WebpackDevServer in webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have looked into this for few hours and can't seem to find an elegant solution.

I need to have build variant of my application where it rebundles my files and assets as I change them, but instead of serving them to WebpackDevServer for hot-swapping it would deploy them to a specific directory. I need this to integrate a build into my cordova-android workflow.

Best solution so far I have is downloading them directly from WebpackDevServer and saving wherever I need, but this is far from elegant solution.

> Webpack version: "1.13.2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack has a watch mode, which compiles the bundle when a file changes. You would run:

```
webpack --watch
```

All you need to do is set the output path to the desired directory in your webpack config:

```
output: {
  path: 'path/to/output/directory'
}
```

Or if you don't want to modify your config you can use the CLI option `--output-path`, which leaves you with:

```
webpack --watch --output-path path/to/output/directory
```

You don't need `webpack-dev-server` for this, but if you still want to use it in parallel you can simply run two processes.

Comment: Thank you I guess this would help, only problem is that I'm building it with node scripts and can't seem to pass --watch to webpack.config.js. I think thats because I'm using webpack v1. Will try to upgrade to v2